# How do I fix npm's global location?

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run

`npm ls -g`

I get back

```
-> /usr/local/lib64/usr/local/bin
(empty)
```

Which is obviously incorrect.  Using `locate` I can see my global modules are installed at `/usr/lib64/node_modules`.  How do I go about correcting this issue?  (I'm running gentoo amd64.)

Answer (score 24):

npm uses a .npmrc file which should be in your home directory. (ie ~/.npmrc) In this file you should see a key value pair with the key being "prefix". Try setting the value to something like "/usr/lib64". So your .npmrc file would have the following in addition to whatever else you put in it:

```
prefix = /usr/lib64
```

Comment: No `~/.npmrc` in my case... only `~/.npm` directory.

Answer (score 19):

For those on Windows the `npmrc` file can be found in `C:\path\to\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc`. You can change the `prefix` as mentioned in the answer by cmaxo. By default it's usually something like `${APPDATA}\npm`.

Answer (score 0):

My default is `${APPDATA}/npm`.

Comment: There is a 30 character requirement because answers using fewer characters are usually bad answers. Instead of adding garbage filler text, which just annoys other users and makes work for us to clean up, why not provide a reference for your claim? Please read [answer].