# How can I change the default location for NPM installs on Windows?

Tags: node.js, npm

When I install modules with NPM on Windows, it installs them to:

```
~/node_modules
```

I'd like to set change this to an arbitrary path such as:

```
c:\dev\repo\node_modules
```

I've tried

```
npm config set prefix <path>
```

With various values but none of them seem to work.

Comment: npm used to be able to do this. But the maintainers of npm have decided to move forward with the philosophy that each project should have its own modules directory to avoid version conflicts. There is still the global `-g` install for OS-wide stuff like command line tools such as grunt and mocha. You still have a limited ability to store modules in an almost arbitrary path due to how `require` searches for module. It first searches in `./node_modules` then `../node_modules` then `../../node_modules` etc.

Comment: This answer worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18264557/1696030 "npmrc file can be found in C:\path\to\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [FAQ](https://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html#Why-can-t-npm-just-put-everything-in-one-place-like-other-package-managers) npm installs modules locally, to avoid dependency conflicts with nesting dependencies. If you really want different projects to reference the same copy you can use [npm link](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-link.html).

Comment: npm link url is 404, presumably is now: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link